# Why am not being able to initialize the Micro-SD?

Tags: sd-card, datalogging

The reason I bought this MicroSD board because to follow their [**guide**](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-micro-sd-breakout-board-card-tutorial/arduino-wiring) 
and I have used the recommend code in:
 File > Example > SD > CardInfo 
also did the slight change in the code for `const int chipSelect = 10;`

Here is the exact code I am using:

```cpp
/*
  SD card test

  This example shows how use the utility libraries on which the'
  SD library is based in order to get info about your SD card.
  Very useful for testing a card when you're not sure whether its working or not.

  The circuit:
    SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11 on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimila
 ** MISO - pin 12 on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimila
 ** CLK - pin 13 on Arduino Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimila
 ** CS - depends on your SD card shield or module.
     Pin 4 used here for consistency with other Arduino examples


  created  28 Mar 2011
  by Limor Fried
  modified 9 Apr 2012
  by Tom Igoe
*/
// include the SD library:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// set up variables using the SD utility library functions:
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;

// change this to match your SD shield or module;
// Arduino Ethernet shield: pin 4
// Adafruit SD shields and modules: pin 10
// Sparkfun SD shield: pin 8
// MKRZero SD: SDCARD_SS_PIN
const int chipSelect = 10;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // change this to 53 on a mega(don't follow this!!)
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH); // Add this line


  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.print("\nInitializing SD card...");

  // we'll use the initialization code from the utility libraries
  // since we're just testing if the card is working!
  if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed. Things to check:");
    Serial.println("* is a card inserted?");
    Serial.println("* is your wiring correct?");
    Serial.println("* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?");
    while (1);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wiring is correct and a card is present.");
  }

  // print the type of card
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Card type:         ");
  switch (card.type()) {
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD1:
      Serial.println("SD1");
      break;
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SD2:
      Serial.println("SD2");
      break;
    case SD_CARD_TYPE_SDHC:
      Serial.println("SDHC");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown");
  }

  // Now we will try to open the 'volume'/'partition' - it should be FAT16 or FAT32
  if (!volume.init(card)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find FAT16/FAT32 partition.\nMake sure you've formatted the card");
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.print("Clusters:          ");
  Serial.println(volume.clusterCount());
  Serial.print("Blocks x Cluster:  ");
  Serial.println(volume.blocksPerCluster());

  Serial.print("Total Blocks:      ");
  Serial.println(volume.blocksPerCluster() * volume.clusterCount());
  Serial.println();

  // print the type and size of the first FAT-type volume
  uint32_t volumesize;
  Serial.print("Volume type is:    FAT");
  Serial.println(volume.fatType(), DEC);

  volumesize = volume.blocksPerCluster();    // clusters are collections of blocks
  volumesize *= volume.clusterCount();       // we'll have a lot of clusters
  volumesize /= 2;                           // SD card blocks are always 512 bytes (2 blocks are 1KB)
  Serial.print("Volume size (Kb):  ");
  Serial.println(volumesize);
  Serial.print("Volume size (Mb):  ");
  volumesize /= 1024;
  Serial.println(volumesize);
  Serial.print("Volume size (Gb):  ");
  Serial.println((float)volumesize / 1024.0);

  Serial.println("\nFiles found on the card (name, date and size in bytes): ");
  root.openRoot(volume);

  // list all files in the card with date and size
  root.ls(LS_R | LS_DATE | LS_SIZE);
}

void loop(void) {
}
```

and this is the schematic I have used as they recommended 
[image]
but the serial monitor keeps outputting `Initializing SD card...initialization failed`  I have tried wiring again and again but I am still getting the same result.

Here are the **[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSe3s.jpg)** of the **wiring and running** the test. 
There is something I'm not sure if it is helpful but after I upload the file and before the serial monitor output:

```cpp
Initializing SD card...initialization failed. Things to check:
* is a card inserted?
* is your wiring correct?
* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?
```

a red led located next to R1 of the MicroSD card starts flashing and before that output, it flashes faster then it stops and I will be presenting with that output.

Things I have tried...

- Different card
- Without the card
- Tried the 3v
- Tried using  pin 4 for chipSelect

Please don't mark as duplicate because I looked at the other and I'm trying to use this guide by this company and also this guide was presenting as a solution for others and here I am using it.

**Edit 1:**

After the writing this question, I had to upload the file again so I can take pictures when I did that this time the serial monitor outputs:

```cpp
23:02:10.089 -> 
23:02:10.089 -> Initializing SD card...initialization failed. Things to check:
23:02:12.106 -> * is a card inserted?
23:02:12.106 -> * is your wiring correct?
23:02:12.106 -> * did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?
```

Looks like I am stuck with that and the only number keep changing

```cpp
23:11:02.769 -> 
23:11:02.769 -> Initializing SD card...initialization failed. Things to check:
23:11:04.778 -> * is a card inserted?
23:11:04.778 -> * is your wiring correct?
23:11:04.778 -> * did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?
```

**Edit 2:**

Sorry but it looks these numbers coming because I did mark the `show timestamps` box by mistake.

Comment: it looks everything ok. check the soldering of the pins of Nano.

Comment: Juraj -Tomorrow I was going to try to test the connective of the pins at school, hopefully, it is the cause.

Comment: Also wiggle the wires in the breadboard. Sometimes they don't make an electrical connection, even thought they are fully pushed in.

Comment: A quick question after only skimming the post, is this an older standard SDCard or one of the High Capacity SDCard which uses a different way to address internal memory?

Comment: @Juraj have checked connectives of all pins and they were good so soldering was alright. I don't know what next I should do

Comment: @Gerben  I have just tried that too and I even did it again in a different breadboard. No luck for me.

Comment: @st2000  I'm a beginner and not really sure about these terminologies but I can tell you I bought my `Micro SD Card Breakout Board` from **adafruit.com**

Comment: @Juraj I did upload new two images there `https://imgur.com/a/B4La8kx`

Comment: I think the SDCard addressing change somewhere around the 8GByte size.  Under and an address gets you a byte.  Above and an address gets you a block of bytes.  The drivers has to be able to handle both.  I think SDCards using the block of bytes approach are labeled "HC".  This has nothing to do with the SDCard break out board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board on the photo is Arduino Micro, not Arduino Nano. Arduino Micro doesn't have SPI on pins 11, 12, 13. Use pins MOSI, MISO and SCK.

- MO to DI
- MI to DO
- SCK to CLK
- you can use any pin as CS, only set it as parameter to `SD.begin()`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, would you explain again! So where are these DI, DO, and CLK located in my Arduino Micro!

Comment: DI, DO and CLK are on the SD module. MISO, MOSI and SCK are on the Arduino

Comment: Alright If this is what you meant 
   
`** MOSI - DI - pin  11`
 `** MISO - DO - pin 12`
 `** SCK - CLK -  pin 13`
 `** CS - pin 4 `  :  but still initialization failed!

Comment: not 11, 12, 13 !!! they don't have a number on Arduino Micro. only labels. see the picture I added to the Answer. on your board there is MO and MI

Comment: Arduino Mini is not Arduino Micro

Comment: I'm confusing. why do you keep editing old comments? Just was curious. unfortunately, I don't have the same as the one micro you posted.

Comment: see on the board SCK is in the corner. MI is MISO and MO is MOSI

Comment: Alright, I see the editing photo, let me apply these changes.

Comment: Alright now I see this 
`Initializing SD card...Wiring is correct and a card is present.`

Comment: This made it worked! Done!